# how to return dataTable serverside response in a model hook of emberjs?

Tags: ember.js, datatables, server-side

Assume that I have a list of customers in database at server. Previously I implemented a model hook of `App.CustomersRoute` to return the list of all customers and then used `{{#each}}` to show these customers in a table `<TR>`. But now as the list of customers is grown to millions, it is not feasible to fetch customers all at once, then bind them to the TABLE in html, and apply `dataTable` on it. Instead, I am using `server-side processing` now which returns limited set of records which are then shown in `dataTable`. So I removed a call to all customers from model hook. Now what I wish to do is get the list of customers returned by `dataTable` query response and assign it back to table's `<TR>` in html and then apply `dataTable` on it (or something similar). How can I do this? Is there any way to assign the response of datatable's server-side processing to the `model` hook of a ember route?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "FnCreatedRow" callback from datatables and try to manipulate your server data from there. Im totally noob in amberjs so i cant help anymore.

Hope this help